# How to speed up this function (for n parameters) in R?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, montecarlo

I have this function:

```
col <- 0
rres <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=nrow(ind),ncol=length(lt)))
gig <- NULL
> lt
     [1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
> delta.1
 [1]   5   7   9  10  12  15  17  20  22  26  29  34  39  46  54  68  96 138 138



> f.bio
    function(x,y,a,b,l,k,m)
    {
       for (t in 1:nrow(y)){
        for (i in  1:length(lt)){
          for(j in 1:delta.1[i]){

        ifelse (t+j-1>nrow(x),gig[j]<-  NA,
                gig[j] <- x[t+j-1,i]*
                  (a*(l-(((l-(lt[i]+1))/(exp(-k*((j-1)/12))))))
                   ^b)*exp(m[(1+j),i]*(j-1)))    

      }
      rres[t,i] <- sum(gig, na.rm = TRUE)
    }
    result <- apply(rres,1,function(x) sum(x)/1000000)  
  }
   return(result)
}
```

which it is apply to some biological data, the code is:

```
f.bio(ind,eff,a_all,b_all,Linf,K_coef,mort)
```

where the arguments are:

```
> dim(ind)
[1] 1356   19
> dim(eff)
[1] 1356    1
a_all = 0.004
b_all= 3
Linf= 19.4
K_coef = 0.57
> dim(mort)
[1] 110  19
```

`ind`, `eff`, and `mort` are data.frame. 
Now, my question is, is possible to apply this function to  `n` parameters, without excessive time machine?
I mean for `n` parameters  a distribution of a certain parameters, for example:

```
 set.seed(1) 
a_all_v <- round(sort(rnorm(40,a_all,0.00034)),5) #40 values!!
```

and so on for the `4 par`: `a_all, b_all, K_coef, Linf`

I wrote this code, with loop ( in this loop i can combine `a_all` with `b_all`, and `Linf` with `K_coef`):

```
col <- 0
for (m1 in 1:length(a_all_v)){ 
  a_all <- a_all_v[m1]
   b_all <- b_all_v[m1]
    for(m2 in 1:length(Linf_v)){ 
      Linf <- Linf_v[m2]
       K_coef <- k_coef_v[m2]
       col <- col+1
         res.temp <-f.bio(ind,eff,a_all,b_all,Linf,K_coef,mort)
          res.2[,col] <-res.temp 
 }
}
```

where res.2 is:

```
res.2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=1356,ncol=1600)) #1600=40*40 (number of values for each parameters distribution)
```

This loop employ many time machine (many day on my PC). For these reason, there is some package or function (like Monte Carlo or bootstrap) that can change my code structure, and run the function with a good number of parameters combination, in little time (if is possible)?

Comment: Is it right: in `f.bio()` you calculate `result` for every `t` but returning only the last? BTW: your `ifelse (t+j-1>nrow(x), ..., ...)` should be better `if (ifelse (t+j-1>nrow(x)) ... else ...`  And `result <- rowSums(rres)/1000000` instead of `result <- apply(rres,1,function(x) sum(x)/1000000)` Are you using `rres` as matrix or as dataframe during calculation? Often coercions cost time.

Comment: rres is a data frame.

Comment: Yes, but `apply(rres, ...)` coerces its first argument to a matrix. Also in `rres[t,i] <- ...` you are using `rres` like a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep your current setup with `for` loops, you need to start preallocating your output objects. For example, you start with an empty `gig` (`NULL`) and iteratively fill it. However, the way you do it right now `gig` needs to be rebuild every iteration as the analysis progresses, and reallocation of memory is a very expensive operation. Simply making `gig` as large as it needs to be and then doing the assignment will speed up your code tremendously.

Even better is to solve your problem not via `for` loops (which are notoriously slow, even with preallocation) but use either:

- Vectorisation, matrix calculations. These will be order of magnitude faster.
- `dplyr` or `data.table`. If smartly used, these will also be much faster, but vectorisation is probably even faster.

Comment: #shamelessselfpromotion :) For more background see the [tutorial I wrote](http://stcorp.nl/R_course/tutorial_control_flow.html).

Comment: but Paul, the gig must be inside the function, or outside? example: gig=data.frame(matrix(nrow=j))?

Comment: You can do both, but I think putting it inside the function is best.

Comment: but for you is better befor the 'for' loop, or after? (because if i put it after the three 'for' loop, the code doesn't work)

Comment: You create an empty object that has the required size before the loops.